# Sequelize Many To Many Relationship : Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to create many to many relationship using Sequelize + nodeJs using existing MySQL Database :

Below is my tables :
 - "usr" Table : usr_id (PK)
 - Intermediate "usr_role" : usr_id, role_id
 - "role" table : role_id

This is my models
"User" Models:

```js
"use strict";
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    usrid  : {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        field:'usr_id'
    },
    name :{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        field:'usr_name'
    },

  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'usr',
    name:'User',
    underscored:'true',

    classMethods: {
      associate:function(models){
        User.belongsToMany(models.Role, { through: 'UserRole', foreignKey:'usr_id', as:'UserRoles'});
      }

    }
  }
);
  return User;
};
```

"Role" models

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
  id  : {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      field:'role_id'
  },
  name :{
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      field:'role_name'
  },

},{
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: 'role_ref',
  underscored:'true',

  classMethods: {
    associate:function(models){
      Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: 'UserRole',
        foreignKey:'role_id'});
     }
  }
}
)
return Role;
};
```

```
E:\nodejsWS\learn\node_modules\inflection\lib\inflection.js:795
var str_path = str.split( '::' );
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at Object.inflector.underscore 
(E:\nodejsWS\learn\node_modules\inflection\lib\inflection.js:795:25)
at Object.module.exports.underscoredIf 
(E:\nodejsWS\learn\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:28:27)
at new BelongsToMany (E:\nodejsWS\learn\node_modules\sequelize
\lib\associations\belongs-to-many.js:134:15)
at Mixin.belongsToMany 
(E:\nodejsWS\learn\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations
\mixin.js:264:21)
at sequelize.define.classMethods.associate 
(E:\nodejsWS\learn\models\Role.js:29:12)
at E:\nodejsWS\learn\models\index.js:50:21
```

this is my index.js

```js
// Import models
  fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
      return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
      var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
      db[model.name] = model;
    });

//associate models
  Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
      console.log(db);
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
  });
```

Line 50 refer to  db[modelName].associate(db), that cause the error.

Can somebody please guide me what's i'm doing wrong. Do i need to manually create intermediate Models 'UserRole'. Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the actual intermediate table's name in the `belongsToMany` config, or define the model `UserRole`. Also, unless your intermediate table has the fields, you'll probably also want to specify `timestamps: false` as well. So, for example:

```
Role.belongsToMany(models.User, {
    through: 'usr_role',
    foreignKey:'role_id',
    timestamps: false
});
```

This will cause sequelize to use that table in the queries it builds without needing a model defined, and will prevent it from requesting the timestamp fields from either the User table or the intermediate.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I have tried to use your solution but the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" still exists. I'm using sequelize version 3.23.6. Thanks